# Expanding functionality of case switching commands in Vim

Tags: vim

In my current work of refactoring a fairly large codebase, I find myself wanting to replace apostrophes and quotes with each other from time to time.

Up until now I've been applying `s/"/'/g` for visual selections I've made, and it works fine.

Recently though, I discovered the tilde (`~`) command. I thought it would be nice if I could expand its functionality to not only change the case of characters, but also exchange `"` with `'` and vice versa. Is it possible to expand its functionality to accomplish this?

Comment: Have a look at the [vim-surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround). With the plugin loaded you can change double to single quotes with `cs"'` (change surrounding from `"` to `'`).

Comment: That"s a great concept, it might even prompt me to look in vim plugin writin".

Comment: I mean "you should get a software patent on the idea; profit!". ;)

Comment: @msw: I was actually thinking about that too, but I was hoping there would be a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Marco points out in the comments, you're probably looking for the [surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround). Using this plugin you can change the surroundings of text. For example:

```
"Hello World"
```

Got inside of the text and pres `cs"'` and the surroundings will change to

```
'Hello World'
```

I would also recommend Tim Pope's [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen#readme) plugin to use to get everything set up. It will also install the help pages. The details on on the github page.